# Is there a name for survival of the fittest in a single family?

Tags: genetics, evolution, human-evolution

Imagine a case where the children of a bird each have a 50% chance of being born blind.

But the bird always has on average 4 chicks. So on average 2 will be blind and 2 sighted.

(Perhaps this could evolve if the energy needed to create a chick with 100% probability of being sighted is more than the energy needed to create two chicks each with 50% probability of being sighted. The eye being a very complicated organ).

Now, the mother brings food to the chicks and only the sighted children eat the food. The blind chicks (the 'runts') are thrown out of the nest. (It is common there being a 'runt' of the litter. So this scenario has some truth in it.)

Thus all adult birds of this species are sighted. (The 'fittest' birds).

(This is a kind of surival of the fittest but in a family setting.)

Is there a name for this kind of process? This could happen in any animal that has on average more than 2 children. Where it might be cost effective not to make sure that 100% of the children are fit, because the weakest will die anyway.

Secondly, imagine a scenario, where there is a surplus of food one year, so that even the 'runts' make it to adulthood. Now, 50% of the adult birds will be blind. And people might say "There is an epidemic of blind birds". Can we make comparrisons with the theory that there is "an epidemic of myopia" in modern human populations, possibly due to modern medicine decreasing childhood mortality?

Comment: "Survival of the fittest" is a flawed summary of natural selection that covers up some nuance in the theory (and was not originally used by Darwin but rather a phrase used to try to explain the theory, and then, probably unfortunately, edited into Darwin's own work). Your question seems to lack a basic understanding of heritability and evolution. In particular, your model seems to not involve a heritable trait.

Comment: `Is there a name for this kind of process?` You described a non-heritable lethal trait with a prevalence of 0.5 (which is very unlikely). Does this answer your first question? I don't understand what you mean by `Where it might be cost effective not to make sure that 100% of the children are fit, because the weakest will die anyway.`. Can you please clarify what is on your mind?

Comment: Your second question starts with `Can we make comparrisons`. One can only compare whatever they want to compare. One can even make analogies. But that does not mean there is much to be taken from it. Can you please write a clearly defined question or, otherwise, maybe just remove this second point.

Comment: @Remi.b Yes, the biology needed to grow a bird with 50% likely of being blind might cost 3 units of energy. But the biology needed to grow a bird with excellent vision might cost 500 units of energy. (Think of buying two cheap cameras vs buying one expensive one.) It might be more cost effective to buy the cheap cameras even though they are likely to be defective. As long as you buy enough of them so that at least some of them work.

Comment: @Bryan. Yes I understand evolution. That is why I asked is there a name for *this* process. Which is not standard evolution.

Comment: @zooby `I understand evolution` Take no offense but the phrasing of everything in your post strongly suggests that you don't have much knowledge in evolutionary biology.

Comment: @zooby You will probably want to have a look at [wikipedia > siblicide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siblicide). A famous example of siblicide (not listed in the wikipedia article) is the case of shark that kill each other in the mother's womb (see [this popular article](https://www.livescience.com/29198-shark-embryos-cannibalize-others.html))

Comment: @Remi Of course i'm no expert. I will look at the shark thing. sounds intriguing.

Comment: I've read The Selfish Gene and Darwin's book. I don't know what else you want from me? Since I wasn't talking about evolutionary biology I don't know how you came to that conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This competitive relationship often goes by the simple and intuitive name of [sibling rivalry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibling_rivalry_(animals)), and its closely related idea of [parent-offspring conflict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parent%E2%80%93offspring_conflict).  While it may seem counter-intuitive for evolution, you must remember that while it's better for the *parents* to have multiple surviving chicks, it's better for the *chick* to have less siblings to compete with for insufficient food.

We *do* in fact, see this type of behavior amongst humans as well: who amongst us with a sibling has not competed for parental resources and affection? Fatalities, though, are much rarer than in birds that routinely have more chicks than they can support, because our species are different.

Comment: Yes, "sibling rivalry" is probably the right phrase. By question is really, whether there is a name for an animal deliberately making children compete in order to weed out the most fittest or healthiest and discard the runts of the litter. (And also since humans used to have lots of children, whether this sibling rivalry is good for health of a population.)

Comment: Also, I make a side point, that if an animal was to stop having lots of children and so there was less sibling rivalry, would this be bad for the health of the species?

Comment: @zooby In general, there's no "deliberately" involved, since you're not talking about animals with sufficient cognitive faculties to make such a choice.  Even with humans, how often do you think that a parent _deliberately_ makes their children compete, vs. falling into it as a side effect of their own choices and patterns?  As for whether it's "good" for the population---it doesn't have to be, it just has to be a stable equilibrium.

Comment: Well I mean deliberate in the sense of a stable equilibrium, like you say, that has evolved over thousands of years. Perhaps birds evolved under the assumption their chicks compete. Perhaps humans evolved to have their children compete, and stopping the children compete will upset the equilibrium and be bad for the population's health however one might define it. Perhaps it is "natural" for humans to have 10 children who fight to the death leaving only the two fittest to reproduce.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, whether there is reasearch into how much "sibling rivalry" is essential for maintaing the health of a population. Or having enough children incase some of them are weak is important vs having only two children and hoping they are both strong.

Comment: @zooby It's a spectrum, and species can end up at different set-points along it.  See, for example the notion of r-selection vs k-selection: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R/K_selection_theory

Comment: I think "r-selection vs k-selection" is pretty much an answer to the question.